# Keras Image Preprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

My training images are downscaled versions of their associated HR image. Thus, the input and the output images aren't the same dimension. For now, I'm using a hand-crafted sample of 13 images, but eventually I would like to be able to use my 500-ish HR (high-resolution) images dataset. This dataset, however, does not have images of the same dimension, so I'm guessing I'll have to crop them in order to obtain a uniform dimension.

I currently have this code set up: it takes a bunch of `512x512x3` images and applies a few transformations to augment the data (flips). I thus obtain a basic set of 39 images in their HR form, and then I downscale them by a factor of 4, thus obtaining my trainset which consits of 39 images of dimension `128x128x3`.

```
import numpy as np

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import skimage
from skimage import transform

from constants import data_path
from constants import img_width
from constants import img_height

from model import setUpModel


def setUpImages():

    train = []
    finalTest = []

    sample_amnt = 11
    max_amnt = 13

    # Extracting images (512x512)
    for i in range(sample_amnt):
        train.append(mpimg.imread(data_path + str(i) + '.jpg'))

    for i in range(max_amnt-sample_amnt):
        finalTest.append(mpimg.imread(data_path + str(i+sample_amnt) + '.jpg'))

    # # TODO: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
    # ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False, samplewise_center=False, featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    #                    samplewise_std_normalization=False, zca_whitening=False, zca_epsilon=1e-06, rotation_range=0,
    #                    width_shift_range=0.0, height_shift_range=0.0, brightness_range=None, shear_range=0.0,
    #                    zoom_range=0.0, channel_shift_range=0.0, fill_mode='nearest', cval=0.0, horizontal_flip=False,
    #                    vertical_flip=False, rescale=None, preprocessing_function=None, data_format=None,
    #                    validation_split=0.0, dtype=None)

    # Augmenting data
    trainData = dataAugmentation(train)
    testData  = dataAugmentation(finalTest)

    setUpData(trainData, testData)


def setUpData(trainData, testData):

    # print(type(trainData))                          # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    # print(len(trainData))                           # 64
    # print(type(trainData[0]))                       # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    # print(trainData[0].shape)                       # (1400, 1400, 3)
    # print(trainData[len(trainData)//2-1].shape)     # (1400, 1400, 3)
    # print(trainData[len(trainData)//2].shape)       # (350, 350, 3)
    # print(trainData[len(trainData)-1].shape)        # (350, 350, 3)

    # TODO: substract mean of all images to all images

    # Separating the training data
    Y_train = trainData[:len(trainData)//2]    # First half is the unaltered data
    X_train = trainData[len(trainData)//2:]    # Second half is the deteriorated data

    # Separating the testing data
    Y_test = testData[:len(testData)//2]  # First half is the unaltered data
    X_test = testData[len(testData)//2:]  # Second half is the deteriorated data

    # Adjusting shapes for Keras input  # TODO: make into a function ?
    X_train = np.array([x for x in X_train])
    Y_train = np.array([x for x in Y_train])
    Y_test = np.array([x for x in Y_test])
    X_test = np.array([x for x in X_test])

    # # Sanity check: display four images (2x HR/LR)
    # plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    # for i in range(2):
    #     plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    #     plt.imshow(Y_train[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    # for i in range(2):
    #     plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1 + 2)
    #     plt.imshow(X_train[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    # plt.show()

    setUpModel(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)


# TODO: possibly remove once Keras Preprocessing is integrated?
def dataAugmentation(dataToAugment):
    print("Starting to augment data")
    arrayToFill = []

    # faster computation with values between 0 and 1 ?
    dataToAugment = np.divide(dataToAugment, 255.)

    # TODO: switch from RGB channels to CbCrY
    # # TODO: Try GrayScale
    # trainingData = np.array(
    #     [(cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8(x * 255), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) / 255).reshape(350, 350, 1) for x in trainingData])
    # validateData = np.array(
    #     [(cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8(x * 255), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) / 255).reshape(1400, 1400, 1) for x in validateData])

    # adding the normal images   (8)
    for i in range(len(dataToAugment)):
        arrayToFill.append(dataToAugment[i])
    # vertical axis flip         (-> 16)
    for i in range(len(arrayToFill)):
        arrayToFill.append(np.fliplr(arrayToFill[i]))
    # horizontal axis flip       (-> 32)
    for i in range(len(arrayToFill)):
        arrayToFill.append(np.flipud(arrayToFill[i]))

    # downsizing by scale of 4   (-> 64 images of 128x128x3)
    for i in range(len(arrayToFill)):
        arrayToFill.append(skimage.transform.resize(
            arrayToFill[i],
            (img_width/4, img_height/4),
            mode='reflect',
            anti_aliasing=True))

    # # Sanity check: display the images
    # plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    # for i in range(64):
    #     plt.subplot(8, 8, i + 1)
    #     plt.imshow(arrayToFill[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    # plt.show()

    return np.array(arrayToFill)
```

My question is: **in my case**, can I use the Preprocessing tool that Keras offers? I would ideally like to be able to input my varying sized images of high quality, crop them (not downsize them) to `512x512x3`, and data augment them through flips and whatnot. Substracting the mean would also be part of what I'd like to achieve. That set would represent my validation set.

Reusing the validation set, I want to downscale by a factor of 4 all the images, and that would generate my training set.

Those two sets could then be split appropriately to obtain, ultimately, the famous `X_train` `Y_train` `X_test` `Y_test`.

I'm just hesitant about throwing out all the work I've done so far to preprocess my mini sample, but I'm thinking if it can all be done with a single built-in function, maybe I should give that a go.

This is my first ML project, hence me not understanding very well Keras, and the documentation isn't always the clearest. I'm thinking that the fact that I'm working with a X and Y that are different in size, maybe this function doesn't apply to my project.

Thank you! :)

Comment: As a general principle, you should remove the chunks of your code that are commented out, and hence irrelevant to the issue in hand

Comment: My bad, I thought maybe if people wanted to play around with the code then they would appreciate a few "unit tests"/"sanity checks" already included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christof Henkel's suggestion is very clean and nice. I would just like to offer another way to do it using [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug), a convenient way to augment images in lots of different ways. It's usefull if you want more implemented augmentations or if you ever need to use some ML library other than Keras.

It unfortunatly doesn't have a way to make crops that way but it allows implementing custom functions. Here is an example function for generating random crops of a set size from an image that's at least as big as the chosen crop size:

```
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa

def random_crop(images, random_state, parents, hooks):
    crop_h, crop_w = 128, 128
    new_images = []
    for img in images:
        if (img.shape[0] >= crop_h) and (img.shape[1] >= crop_w):
            rand_h = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[0]-crop_h)
            rand_w = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[1]-crop_w)
            new_images.append(img[rand_h:rand_h+crop_h, rand_w:rand_w+crop_w])
        else:
             new_images.append(np.zeros((crop_h, crop_w, 3)))
    return np.array(new_images)

def keypoints_dummy(keypoints_on_images, random_state, parents, hooks):
    return keypoints_on_images

cropper = iaa.Lambda(func_images=random_crop, func_keypoints=keypoints_dummy)
```

You can then combine this function with any other builtin imgaug function, for example the flip functions that you're already using like this:

```
seq = iaa.Sequential([cropper, iaa.Fliplr(0.5), iaa.Flipud(0.5)])
```

This function could then generate lots of different crops from each image. An example image with some possible results (note that it would result in actual (128, 128, 3) images, they are just merged into one image here for visualization):

[image: Original image]

[image: Crops]

Your image set could then be generated by:

```
crops_per_image = 10
images = [skimage.io.imread(path) for path in glob.glob('train_data/*.jpg')]
augs = np.array([seq.augment_image(img)/255 for img in images for _ in range(crops_per_image)])
```

It would also be simple to add new functions to be applied to the images, for example the remove mean functions you mentioned.

Comment: You again! Haha. This is an interesting approach. If I'm understanding properly, this crop function of yours would actually go within the network itself, rather than being executed beforehand in order to generate the set itself ? (I'm basing this observation off the fact that I see the keywords `Lambda` and `Sequential` in there. I could be totally wrong.)

Comment: Hi again :) You could write is a as function and use it as a generator like in Christof's answer but as I've written the above example it would be used to generate the whole training set beforehand. Using the fit_generator function can lead to decreased overfitting due to constantly training on new images. However if the network is small (so that updating the network doesn't take much time) and the image augmentation takes a lot of time this can considerable increase training time. So it's nice being able to do both and then trying what works best.

Comment: I'm still hesitant about using the Preprocessing tool. Say I use `rotation_range`: I'm guessing they have made it so that this thing only applies to X, and not Y since usually Y isn't related to X in dimensionality (X is an image, Y is a classification, for example). Thus, `rotation_range` would be built-in so that it only modifies X, but in -my- case I would -require- all transformations applied to X to also be applied to Y, except for the very last transformation on X which would be, in pseudo-code: `X.scale = (Y.scale)/4`. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this well. :/

Comment: I must also ask: is `imgaug` available for Anaconda? I've been looking online and it doesn't seem like it's the case.

Comment: Hm, yes I see what you mean. I have never used it when the output needs to be augmented aswell, only for classification problems where Y isn't affected. Afraid I don't know the answer to that. I don't know about imgaug on conda either but you can install it with pip in any virtual conda env.

Comment: I went for a modified version of your `random_crop` function which works wonderfully. Thank you very much again, sir!

Comment: Also, is it me or should your line `if (img.shape[0] >= crop_h) and (img.shape[1] >= crop_w):` go before `for img in images:` ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use keras preprocessing function. Below some snippets to help you...

```
def cropping_function(x):
    ...
    return cropped_image

X_image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = cropping_function,
                               horizontal_flip = True, 
                               vertical_flip=True)
X_train_flow = X_image_gen.flow(X_train, batch_size = 16, seed = 1)
Y_image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True, 
                                 vertical_flip=True)
Y_train_flow = Y_image_gen.flow(y_train, batch_size = 16, seed = 1)
train_flow = zip(X_train_flow,Y_train_flow)
model.fit_generator(train_flow)
```

Comment: I would need to replace my current `model.fit` with this version using the generator, right? I see no parameter for `batch_size`, where do I set that? And how does the `shuffle` parameter work: would it shuffle only `X_train` and accordingly shuffle the same way `Y_train`, for example? Finally, and most importantly, where do I specify that I want the generated `X_train` to be of dimension precisely 4 times smaller than the generated `Y_train` (to be more specific, I'm working with `128x128x3` and `512x512x3`)? The way I see the code, it looks like I would obtain the same size for X and Y_train

Comment: "I would need to replace my current model.fit with this version using the generator, right?" Yes.

batchsize is parameter of flow (I adjusted above). 

shuffle does shuffle X and Y in the same way, you would define the cropping (4 time smaller) in the "cropping function" it will only be applied to X

Comment: Would `horizontal_flip` and `vertical_flip` only apply to X, and not to Y ? That would be bad, in my case. I would need rotations and flips to apply to both X and Y, but noise should be added only on X (if there is an option for that).

Comment: You are right. Its probably best to split into two generators with different arguments (see above)

Comment: But now that you've split in two different arguments that both include "flips", will those flips be symmetrical? It's a requirement.

Comment: Yes, since both generators have the same seed

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, but there's always some kind of limitation. The `x_train` has to be generated by downsizing the corresponding `y_train` which itself was cropped (with a function similar to the one provided by sds, below) from the initial image in a directory. Trying to use `.flow_from_directory` I realized I -have- to set the `target_size=` parameter to something and I do not know how to basically just to Keras to ignore it since the resizing is done in my `preprocessing_function` later on. See this code: https://pastebin.com/KX0VTnV7

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way performing random and center crop *before resizing* using native `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory`. You can add it as `preprocess_crop.py` module into your project.

It first resizes image preserving aspect ratio and then performs crop. Resized image size is based on `crop_fraction` which is hardcoded but can be changed. See `crop_fraction = 0.875` line where 0.875 appears to be the most common, e.g. 224px crop from 256px image.

Note that the implementation has been done by monkey patching `keras_preprocessing.image.utils.loag_img` function as I couldn't find any other way to perform crop before resizing without rewriting many other classes above.

Due to these limitations, the cropping method is enumerated into the `interpolation` field. Methods are delimited by `:` where the first part is interpolation and second is crop e.g. `lanczos:random`. Supported crop methods are `none`, `center`, `random`. When no crop method is specified, `none` is assumed.

#### How to use it

Just drop the `preprocess_crop.py` into your project to enable cropping. The example below shows how you can use random cropping for the training and center cropping for validation:

```py
import preprocess_crop
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input

#...

# Training with random crop

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    channel_shift_range=20,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)

train_img_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size  = BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode  = 'categorical',
    interpolation = 'lanczos:random', # <--------- random crop
    shuffle = True
)

# Validation with center crop

validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)

validate_img_generator = validate_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validate_dir,
    target_size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size  = BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode  = 'categorical',
    interpolation = 'lanczos:center', # <--------- center crop
    shuffle = False
)
```

Here's `preprocess_crop.py` file to include with your project:

```py
import random
import keras_preprocessing.image

def load_and_crop_img(path, grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb', target_size=None,
             interpolation='nearest'):
    """Wraps keras_preprocessing.image.utils.loag_img() and adds cropping.
    Cropping method enumarated in interpolation
    # Arguments
        path: Path to image file.
        color_mode: One of "grayscale", "rgb", "rgba". Default: "rgb".
            The desired image format.
        target_size: Either `None` (default to original size)
            or tuple of ints `(img_height, img_width)`.
        interpolation: Interpolation and crop methods used to resample and crop the image
            if the target size is different from that of the loaded image.
            Methods are delimited by ":" where first part is interpolation and second is crop
            e.g. "lanczos:random".
            Supported interpolation methods are "nearest", "bilinear", "bicubic", "lanczos",
            "box", "hamming" By default, "nearest" is used.
            Supported crop methods are "none", "center", "random".
    # Returns
        A PIL Image instance.
    # Raises
        ImportError: if PIL is not available.
        ValueError: if interpolation method is not supported.
    """

    # Decode interpolation string. Allowed Crop methods: none, center, random
    interpolation, crop = interpolation.split(":") if ":" in interpolation else (interpolation, "none")  

    if crop == "none":
        return keras_preprocessing.image.utils.load_img(path, 
                                            grayscale=grayscale, 
                                            color_mode=color_mode, 
                                            target_size=target_size,
                                            interpolation=interpolation)

    # Load original size image using Keras
    img = keras_preprocessing.image.utils.load_img(path, 
                                            grayscale=grayscale, 
                                            color_mode=color_mode, 
                                            target_size=None, 
                                            interpolation=interpolation)

    # Crop fraction of total image
    crop_fraction = 0.875
    target_width = target_size[1]
    target_height = target_size[0]

    if target_size is not None:        
        if img.size != (target_width, target_height):

            if crop not in ["center", "random"]:
                raise ValueError('Invalid crop method {} specified.', crop)

            if interpolation not in keras_preprocessing.image.utils._PIL_INTERPOLATION_METHODS:
                raise ValueError(
                    'Invalid interpolation method {} specified. Supported '
                    'methods are {}'.format(interpolation,
                        ", ".join(keras_preprocessing.image.utils._PIL_INTERPOLATION_METHODS.keys())))

            resample = keras_preprocessing.image.utils._PIL_INTERPOLATION_METHODS[interpolation]

            width, height = img.size

            # Resize keeping aspect ratio
            # result shold be no smaller than the targer size, include crop fraction overhead
            target_size_before_crop = (target_width/crop_fraction, target_height/crop_fraction)
            ratio = max(target_size_before_crop[0] / width, target_size_before_crop[1] / height)
            target_size_before_crop_keep_ratio = int(width * ratio), int(height * ratio)
            img = img.resize(target_size_before_crop_keep_ratio, resample=resample)

            width, height = img.size

            if crop == "center":
                left_corner = int(round(width/2)) - int(round(target_width/2))
                top_corner = int(round(height/2)) - int(round(target_height/2))
                return img.crop((left_corner, top_corner, left_corner + target_width, top_corner + target_height))
            elif crop == "random":
                left_shift = random.randint(0, int((width - target_width)))
                down_shift = random.randint(0, int((height - target_height)))
                return img.crop((left_shift, down_shift, target_width + left_shift, target_height + down_shift))

    return img

# Monkey patch
keras_preprocessing.image.iterator.load_img = load_and_crop_img
```