# Keras) How to get input and output image from callback to visualize in tensorboard

Tags: keras, tensorboard, tf.keras

First of all,

### I must use the function *fit_generator()* , **model.fit_generator(...)**

In this situation, I have to visualize the input image and output image by tensorboard.

Even though I use the tensorboard callback like below, it didn't visualize image at all.

```
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_images=True)
model.fit_generator(..., callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I saw many posts related to this issue([a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784921/how-to-display-custom-images-in-tensorboard-using-keras?rq=1),[b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469866/displaying-images-on-tensorboard-through-keras)) and found some hints to implement custom callback class. However, there was no way to get the input image and output image to write into tensorboard.

Please help, thanks