# Keras pre-trained model switching to varying input size

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Very much similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41092113/9768291) except I am wondering how I could take my **pre-trained model** which had an input size of `(128, 128, 3)` images, keep its weights, and use it to `predict` on images of varying input size.

I get this, as it is, when I try to input an image of arbitrary size:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arg_test.py", line 127, in <module>
    predict(args)
  File "arg_test.py", line 71, in predict
    predictions.append(model.predict(input_img)[0])  # returns a list of lists, one for each image in the batch
  File "C:\Users\payne\Anaconda3\envs\ml-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1147, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "C:\Users\payne\Anaconda3\envs\ml-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 749, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\payne\Anaconda3\envs\ml-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 137, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (128, 128, 3) but got array with shape (2736, 3648, 3)
```

Here is [my model](https://github.com/payne911/SR-ResCNN-Keras-/blob/master/model.py):

```
def setUpModel(x_train, y_train):
    filters = 256
    kernel_size = 3
    strides = 1

    # Head module
    input = Input(shape=(img_height//scale_fact, img_width//scale_fact, img_depth))
    conv0 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(input)

    # Body module
    res = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(conv0)
    act = ReLU()(res)
    res = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(act)
    res_rec = Add()([conv0, res])

    for i in range(res_blocks):
        res1 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(res_rec)
        act  = ReLU()(res1)
        res2 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(act)
        res_rec = Add()([res_rec, res2])

    conv = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(res_rec)
    add  = Add()([conv0, conv])

    # Tail module
    conv = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(add)
    act  = ReLU()(conv)
    up   = UpSampling2D(size=scale_fact if scale_fact != 4 else 2)(act)  # TODO: try "Conv2DTranspose"
    # mul = Multiply([np.zeros((img_width,img_height,img_depth)).fill(0.1), up])(up)

    # When it's a 4X factor, we want the upscale split in two procedures
    if(scale_fact == 4):
        conv = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(up)
        act  = ReLU()(conv)
        up   = UpSampling2D(size=2)(act)  # TODO: try "Conv2DTranspose"

    output = Conv2D(filters=3,
                    kernel_size=1,
                    strides=1,
                    padding='same')(up)

    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

This was only the architecture of the model that was used during training, but tha training is behind: I have my `model.h5` file obtained through `model.save()`.

Here is how I get predictions:

```
import argparse
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.io

from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta

from constants import save_dir
from constants import model_name
from constants import crops_p_img
from constants import tests_path
from constants import img_height
from constants import img_width
from constants import scale_fact
from utils import float_im
from utils import crop_center


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('-a', '--amount', type=int, default=crops_p_img,
                    help='how many (cropped to 128x128) samples to predict from within the image')
parser.add_argument('image', type=str,
                    help='image name (example: "bird.png") that must be inside the "./input/" folder')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--model', type=str, default=model_name,
                    help='model name (in the "./save/" folder), followed by ".h5"')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--random', action="store_true",  # if var is in args, set to TRUE, else, set to FALSE
                    help='flag that will select a random 128x128 area in the input image instead of the center')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--full', action="store_true",  # if var is in args, set to TRUE, else, set to FALSE
                    help='(WIP) flag that will get the whole image to be processed by the network')

args = parser.parse_args()


def predict(args):
    model = load_model(save_dir + '/' + args.model)

    # Setting up the proper optimizer       TODO: needed?
    if args.model == "my_full_model.h5":
        optimizer = Adadelta(lr=1.0,
                             rho=0.95,
                             epsilon=None,
                             decay=0.0)
    else:
        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001,
                         beta_1=0.9,
                         beta_2=0.999,
                         epsilon=None,
                         decay=0.0,
                         amsgrad=False)

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss='mean_squared_error')

    image = skimage.io.imread(tests_path + args.image)

    if image.shape[0] == 128:
        args.amount = 1

    predictions = []
    images = []

    # TODO: integrate FULL IMAGE
    # if args.full:
    #     images.append(image)
    #     # Hack because GPU can only handle one image at a time
    #     input_img = (np.expand_dims(images[0], 0))  # Add the image to a batch where it's the only member
    #     predictions.append(model.predict(input_img)[0])  # returns a list of lists, one for each image in the batch
    # else:
    if True:
        for i in range(args.amount):
            # Cropping to fit input size
            if (args.random or args.amount > 1) and image.shape[0] > 128:
                images.append(random_crop(image))
            else:
                images.append(crop_center(image, img_width//scale_fact, img_height//scale_fact))

            input_img = (np.expand_dims(images[i], 0))
            predictions.append(model.predict(input_img)[0])

    for i in range(len(predictions)):
        show_pred_output(images[i], predictions[i])


# adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463034/9768291
def random_crop(img):
    crop_h, crop_w = img_width//scale_fact, img_height//scale_fact
    print("Shape of input image to crop:", img.shape[0], img.shape[1])

    if (img.shape[0] >= crop_h) and (img.shape[1] >= crop_w):
        # Cropping a random part of the image
        rand_h = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[0]-crop_h)
        rand_w = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[1]-crop_w)
        print("Random position for the crop:", rand_h, rand_w)
        tmp_img = img[rand_h:rand_h+crop_h, rand_w:rand_w+crop_w]

        new_img = float_im(tmp_img)  # From [0,255] to [0.,1.]
    else:
        return img

    return new_img


def show_pred_output(input, pred):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    plt.suptitle("Results")

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.title("Input: 128x128")
    plt.imshow(input, cmap=plt.cm.binary).axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.title("Output: 512x512")
    plt.imshow(pred, cmap=plt.cm.binary).axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("   -  ", args)
    predict(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this line:

```
input = Input(shape=(None, None, img_depth))
```

`None` in an shape means variable size. Since the model is just convolutions it should work with images of any size.

Comment: However, changing this line would only affect my training session and the subsequent models saved. My current question is about not requiring to train anymore: I -already- have the parameters/weights of my model which I've obtained through `model.save()`.

Comment: @payne No, you still need to define a model that accepts variable sized inputs, and then once the model is defined and instantiated, you can load whatever weights you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: could you provide some example code/more explanations in your answer? You're saying I can instantiate a new model and apply the saved weights of my other model on it? As it was, I was able to predict with the saved weights without instanciating a model (though I was unsure if I was supposed to compile with the same optimizer beforehand since the saved model includes more than just the weigths).

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You'll need to retrain with the new shape unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

After training your model with a specific input shape you can save the trained model weights by using `model.save_weights()` and then assign those weights to the model that has unknown shape by using `model1.load_weights()`.

For example, i have trained the model with input-shape (28,28,1)

```
model=keras.Sequential([
                        keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1)),
                        keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                        keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                        keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                        keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                        keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')
])
```

After training you can save model weights by

```
model.save_weights('model-weights')
```

Then define a model with unknown input shape

```
model2=keras.Sequential([
                        keras.Input(shape=(None,None,1)),
                        keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                        keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                        keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                        keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                        keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')
])
```

Then assign the saved weights by

```
model2.load_weights('/content/model-weights')
```

Now you can predict with model 2 without training it. For more details, please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/7003a88692889ae564548f86c5730020). Thank You!