# Concatenating multiple images into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy

This function receives a list of numpy arrays that consist of cropped parts of an image. The crops are all the same size, except for the right-most and bottom-most images which might be of smaller size.

`predictions[2]` would return the 3rd sub-image that was cropped from the original image. Each crop is a numpy array. There are WxH crops, enumerated from left to right, top to bottom (so if there are 4 sub-images constituting the width, the 5th image in `predictions` would be the first sub-image on the left from the 2nd row of sub-images).

`crops` contains the necessary information to find number of horizontal and vertical images that will constitute the reconstructed images. `crops[2][3]` will contain the 3rd from the top, 4th from the left image cropped.

The images contained by `crops` are of smaller dimension than the ones in `predictions` (I am basically making a model that increases the resolution of images). The reconstructed image if from the images in `predictions`, arranged in the same order as the ones in `crops`.

```
def reconstruct(predictions, crops):
    if len(crops) != 0:
        print("use crops")

    # TODO: properly extract the size of the full image
    width_length = 0
    height_length = 0

    full_image = np.empty(shape=(height_length, width_length))
    print(full_image.shape)

    # TODO: properly merge the crops back into a single image
    for height in range(len(predictions[0])):
        for width in range(len(predictions)):
            # concatenate here
            print(height, width)

    return full_image
```

I was going to use [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), but according to other answers I've seen on SO it wouldn't be an efficient way of doing it (apparently numpy will just recreate a new variable in memory, copy the old one, and add the new data, etc.). So now I'm left wondering how to properly merge my multiple images into a single image. The current idea I was going for was to create a python list of the proper shape and progressively fill it with each numpy array's data, but even that I'm not sure if it's the proper idea.

Here is more or less the kind of bunch of images I'm trying to concatenate into a single image:

[image: split images]

Here is the expected result:

[image: expected result]

And to help you out with understanding what more might be available to you, here is some more code:

```
def predict(args):
    model = load_model(save_dir + '/' + args.model)
    image = skimage.io.imread(tests_path + args.image)

    predictions = []
    images = []

    crops = seq_crop(image)  # crops into multiple sub-parts the image based on 'input_' constants

    for i in range(len(crops)):  # amount of vertical crops
        for j in range(len(crops[0])):  # amount of horizontal crops
            current_image = crops[i][j]
            images.append(current_image)

        # Hack because GPU can only handle one image at a time
        input_img = (np.expand_dims(images[p], 0))       # Add the image to a batch where it's the only member
        predictions.append(model.predict(input_img)[0])  # returns a list of lists, one for each image in the batch

    return predictions, image, crops


# adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463034/9768291
def seq_crop(img):
    """
    To crop the whole image in a list of sub-images of the same size.
    Size comes from "input_" variables in the 'constants' (Evaluation).
    Padding with 0 the Bottom and Right image.

    :param img: input image
    :return: list of sub-images with defined size
    """
    width_shape = ceildiv(img.shape[1], input_width)
    height_shape = ceildiv(img.shape[0], input_height)
    sub_images = []  # will contain all the cropped sub-parts of the image

    for j in range(height_shape):
        horizontal = []
        for i in range(width_shape):
            horizontal.append(crop_precise(img, i*input_width, j*input_height, input_width, input_height))
        sub_images.append(horizontal)

    return sub_images

def crop_precise(img, coord_x, coord_y, width_length, height_length):
    """
    To crop a precise portion of an image.
    When trying to crop outside of the boundaries, the input to padded with zeros.

    :param img: image to crop
    :param coord_x: width coordinate (top left point)
    :param coord_y: height coordinate (top left point)
    :param width_length: width of the cropped portion starting from coord_x
    :param height_length: height of the cropped portion starting from coord_y
    :return: the cropped part of the image
    """

    tmp_img = img[coord_y:coord_y + height_length, coord_x:coord_x + width_length]

    return float_im(tmp_img)  # From [0,255] to [0.,1.]

# from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511341/9768291
def ceildiv(a, b):
    """
    To get the ceiling of a division
    :param a:
    :param b:
    :return:
    """
    return -(-a // b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    preds, original, crops = predict(args)  # returns the predictions along with the original

    # TODO: reconstruct image
    enhanced = reconstruct(preds, crops)  # reconstructs the enhanced image from predictions
```

**EDIT**:

The answer worked. Here is the version I've used:

```
# adapted from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52733370/9768291
def reconstruct(predictions, crops):

    # unflatten predictions
    def nest(data, template):
        data = iter(data)
        return [[next(data) for _ in row] for row in template]

    predictions = nest(predictions, crops)

    H = np.cumsum([x[0].shape[0] for x in predictions])
    W = np.cumsum([x.shape[1] for x in predictions[0]])
    D = predictions[0][0]
    recon = np.empty((H[-1], W[-1], D.shape[2]), D.dtype)
    for rd, rs in zip(np.split(recon, H[:-1], 0), predictions):
        for d, s in zip(np.split(rd, W[:-1], 1), rs):
            d[...] = s
    return recon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient is probably `np.block`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import Image

# get example picture
data = misc.face()
# chop it up
I, J = map(np.arange, (200, 200), data.shape[:2], (200, 200))
chops = [np.split(row, J, axis=1) for row in np.split(data, I, axis=0)]

# do something with the bits

predictions = [chop-(i+j)*(chop>>3) for j, row in enumerate(chops) for i, chop in enumerate(row)]

# unflatten predictions
def nest(data, template):
    data = iter(data)
    return [[next(data) for _ in row] for row in template]

pred_lol = nest(predictions, chops)

# almost builtin reconstruction
def np_block_2D(chops):
    return np.block([[[x] for x in row] for row in chops])

recon = np_block_2D(pred_lol)
Image.fromarray(recon).save('demo.png')
```

Reconstructed manipulated image:

[image]

But we can do faster than that by avoiding intermediary arrays. Instead, we copy into a preallocated array:

```
def speed_block_2D(chops):
    H = np.cumsum([x[0].shape[0] for x in chops])
    W = np.cumsum([x.shape[1] for x in chops[0]])
    D = chops[0][0]
    recon = np.empty((H[-1], W[-1], D.shape[2]), D.dtype)
    for rd, rs in zip(np.split(recon, H[:-1], 0), chops):
        for d, s in zip(np.split(rd, W[:-1], 1), rs):
            d[...] = s
    return recon
```

Timings, also including a generalized ND-ready variant of each method:

```
numpy 2D:               0.991 ms
prealloc 2D:            0.389 ms
numpy general:          1.021 ms
prealloc general:       0.448 ms
```

Code for general case and timings:

```
def np_block(chops):
    d = 0
    tl = chops
    while isinstance(tl, list):
        tl = tl[0]
        d += 1
    if d < tl.ndim:
        def adjust_depth(L):
            if isinstance(L, list):
                return [adjust_depth(l) for l in L]
            else:
                ret = L
                for j in range(d, tl.ndim):
                    ret = [ret]
                return ret
        chops = adjust_depth(chops)
    return np.block(chops)

def speed_block(chops):
    def line(src, i):
        while isinstance(src, list):
            src = src[0]
        return src.shape[i]
    def hyper(src, i):
        src = iter(src)
        fst = next(src)
        if isinstance(fst, list):
            res, dtype, szs = hyper(fst, i+1)
            szs.append([res[i], *(line(s, i) for s in src)])
            res[i] = sum(szs[-1])
            return res, dtype, szs
        res = np.array(fst.shape)
        szs = [res[i], *(s.shape[i] for s in src)]
        res[i] = sum(szs)
        return res, fst.dtype, [szs]
    shape, dtype, szs = hyper(chops, 0)
    recon = np.empty(shape, dtype)
    def cpchp(dst, src, i, szs=None):
        szs = np.array(hyper(src, i)[2]) if szs is None else szs
        dst = np.split(dst, np.cumsum(szs[-1][:-1]), i)
        if isinstance(src[0], list):
            szs = szs[:-1]
            for ds, sr in zip(dst, src):
                cpchp(ds, sr, i+1, szs)
                szs = None
        else:
            for ds, sr in zip(dst, src):
                ds[...] = sr
    cpchp(recon, chops, 0, np.array(szs))
    return recon

from timeit import timeit

T = (timeit(lambda: speed_block(pred_lol), number=1000),
     timeit(lambda: np_block(pred_lol), number=1000),
     timeit(lambda: speed_block_2D(pred_lol), number=1000),
     timeit(lambda: np_block_2D(pred_lol), number=1000))

assert (np.all(speed_block(pred_lol)==np_block(pred_lol)) and
        np.all(speed_block_2D(pred_lol)==np_block(pred_lol)) and
        np.all(speed_block(pred_lol)==np_block_2D(pred_lol)))

print(f"""
numpy 2D:          {T[3]:10.3f} ms
prealloc 2D:       {T[2]:10.3f} ms
numpy general:     {T[1]:10.3f} ms
prealloc general:  {T[0]:10.3f} ms
""")
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. However, I do get an error from this line: `recon = np.empty((H[-1], W[-1], D.shape[2]), D.dtype)`. Error is: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. More specifically, I think it comes from `D.shape[2]`. I'll try to fix it and come back to you.

Comment: Well, I can't edit the comment after 5 minutes. I changed it to `D.shape[1]` and thus get `3` as a result (since my images are RGB). But then the `d[...] = s` line gives me this error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,3) into shape (512,3,3)`. I'm having trouble debugging since I don't really know that kind of notation.

Comment: I've just realized I made a mistake in my OP: I edited it. `predictions` is an array list containing the multiple sub-images cropped from the original image... I forgot the first index which is the `cropped_image` number (so if the original image was cropped into 12 images, the first index of `predictions` ranges from 0 to 11).

Comment: It's a list of all the cropped parts of the original image (which are all numpy arrays). So if the original was cropped in 12 smaller images, it's a list of 12 elements.

Comment: I've added `crops = crops[0]` at the beginning of your function to test it out (as you've asked), and it crashes at `W = np.cumsum([x.shape[1] for x in predictions[0]])` with the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. See: https://pastebin.com/36VpWwkX

Comment: OP did mention it was a list of numpy arrays, and to obtain those, you access them through the normal list notation of python, hence the possible confusion. My bad. I've tried the generalized version. Error is `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,332,3) into shape (512,512,3)` at the line `ds[...] = sr`. It seems it's one of the edge-case where the images on the right-border or the bottom-border aren't necessarily filling out the whole space of the general maximum.

Comment: I'm very sorry for all the confusion. I've added all the relevant code in the OP to be able to fully see how the data is being handled (I removed certain parts that didn't seem too relevant). You are absolutely right that as it is, my reconstruction couldn't happen properly because there would be no way to know the shape of the image. I've edited my code accordingly to include the "crops" variable which has the information I was first talking about (out of confusion) in the original OP.

Comment: @payne Ok, the quickest fix was to structure predictions in the same way as chops/crops---function `nest` in the revised code. Let me know whether that works for you.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MVP! Thank you so much for all your efforts.